# Apache Spark: How do I convert an RDD[(String, String)] into a Array[String] in scala-spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

The code i am running looks like this

```
val termCounts: Array[(String, Long)] = tokenized.flatMap(_.map(_ -> 1L)).reduceByKey(_ + _).collect().sortBy(-_._2)
//   vocabArray: Chosen vocab (removing common terms)
val numStopwords = 20
val stopWord = sc.wholeTextFiles(".../stopword.txt")
val vocabArray1: Array[String] =
termCounts.takeRight(termCounts.size - numStopwords).map(_._1) 
val vocabArray = vocabArray1 diff stopWord
```

see, i wanted to use the diff function and it only works with same types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use sc.wholeTextFiles("/root/folder/to/textfiles/")  it will read each part file in that folder into a String.

So if your set up is

```
  /root/folder/to/textfiles/
   .../part1.txt
   .../part2.txt
   .../part3.txt
```

part1.txt, part2.txt, part3.txt are all read as single records. So your RDD[(String, String)] would be a pair of path to file name and the whole file as a string.

like so.

```
    ("/root/folder/to/text/files/part1.txt", "actual contents of part1.txt as a String"),
    ("/root/folder/to/text/files/part2.txt", "actual contents of part2.txt as a String")
    ...
```

You probably want to tokenize the actual contents of each file before mapping them.

```
  stopWord.flatMap(tokenize(_._2)).collect()
```